# SQL Deleting a child in a subtree where the same id may exist in other subtrees

Tags: sql

```
COPY directories (p, c, lvl) FROM stdin;
AA  AA  1
BB  BB  1
CC  CC  1
DD  DD  1
AA  BB  2
AA  CC  2
AA  DD  2
BB  CC  2
BB  DD  2
CC  DD  2
AA  DD  3
BB  DD  3
```

trying to delete a child whose id can exist in other subtrees.

eg. w/ the data given

When deleting BB  DD  2, I would like to delete AA  DD  3 only if DD does not exist in any other subtree such as CC  DD  2

```
select * from directories 
where p in (
       SELECT p FROM directories 
       WHERE c = 'DD' 
       GROUP BY p HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
) 
and lvl >= 2 and c = 'DD';
```

DELETE BB   DD   2
Expected Rows

```
AA  AA  1
BB  BB  1
CC  CC  1
DD  DD  1  

AA  BB  2
AA  CC  2
AA  DD  2
BB  CC  2  
BB  DD  2   <-- Deleted
CC  DD  2   <-- DD exists, CC is a child of AA (AA  CC  2) so do not delete AA   DD   3

AA  DD  3   <-- Delete If only and only If DD does not exist any other subtree except for depth = 1 (DD   DD   1)
BB  DD  3
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgres here?  Big difference for this question.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: I am currently using postgres, but I have used mysql. If a potential answer is in mysql I could probably figure it out in postgres.

Comment: Please show desired output. Not clear what is being or needed to be deleted. It seems from example, nothing should.

Comment: I've gone ahead and added output